# accessing an element of a class in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to access different id's (with same name) using $this in jquery, but its not working.
I want when a superhero is clicked only his friend and he himself change their class only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery 2.0.0 Online</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shikhar').click(function(){
            $(this).find('#a').click(function(){
                $(this).find('#b').addClass("selected");
                $(this).find('#a').addClass("highlight");
            });
            $(this).find('#b').click(function(){
                $(this).find('#a').addClass("selected");
                $(this).find('#b').addClass("highlight");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
.selected { 
    color:red; 
}
.highlight { 
    background:yellow; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="shikhar">
    <div id="a">Spiderman</div>
    <div id="b">Hulk</div>
</div>
<div class="shikhar">
    <div id="a">Superman</div>
    <div id="b">Batman</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have `id="a"` in both DIVs.

Comment: Change `<div id="a">` to `<div class="a">`. Once that's done, use `$('.a')` to find the matching divs.

Answer (score 1):

ID attributes must be unique. JavaScript stops searching as soon as it finds the *first* element with a matching ID. Simply change those IDs into classes instead:

```
<div class="a">Spiderman</div>
...
<div class="a">Superman</div>
```

Then change your jQuery selectors to `$('.a')` and `$('.b')` instead:

```
$(this).find('.a').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.b').addClass("selected");
    $(this).find('.a').addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: Looks like what I said. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate ids. IDs should be unique. You can use the markup:

```
 <div class="shikhar">
  <div class="a">Spiderman</div>
  <div class="b">Hulk</div>
 </div>
 <div class="shikhar">
  <div class="a">Superman</div>
  <div class="b">Batman</div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$('.shikhar').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.a').click(function(){
            $(this).next().addClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("highlight");

        });
        $(this).find('.b').click(function(){
            $(this).prev().addClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("highlight");

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use the same ID for different elements. use ID for only one element.

HTML:

```
<div class="shikhar">

    <div class="a">Spiderman</div>
    <div class="b">Hulk</div>

</div>


<div class="shikhar">

    <div class="a">Superman</div>
    <div class="b">Batman</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.shikhar').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click','.a, .b',function(){
        $(this).closest('.shikhar').children().removeClass('selected highlight');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/me2DE/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.shikhar >').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(this).siblings('div').addClass("selected");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/S5rbz/ 
 But it's wrong to have more items with the same `id` value on the same page. So replace the id's with `class` values.
Later edit: also, I think you want to remove the existing class, for each children, and add the new class, as if you keep adding the classes, they will be overwritten by the last named class(also keep in mind the cascading rule declarations).